# Error while submiting disavow file to google

Tags: google-search-console, disavow-links

While trying to submit new disavow file to google got error:

```
Error in disavow links file at line 3347, column 1:
Domain line with invalid domain.
domain:lord.of.the.rings.-.the.battle.for.middle-earthg.cracks.me.uk
```

But actually this is working domain i had received from google webmaster tools.
Since there is no possibility to disavow all subdomains like

```
domain:cracks.me.uk
```

the question is - what can i do?

Comment: It sounds like a code error on Googles end since these are valid characters for a domain name. Not much you can do about it but to post this question on the Google forums that apply. Google does quietly look at these and sometimes an employee will chime in. I suggest while you are at it, give solutions that can make the product/tool better or easier to use.

Comment: Some times if you don't get an answer in the Google forums, you could try attending a Google Webmasters Hangout and ask there:  https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/office-hours

Comment: I can't visit that site.   Are you sure the domain actually is valid?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but an answer can still be provided for current knowledge...

While at the time this question was posted there was no way to disavow a whole domain name Google has made the change to support that. You can add `domain:domain.com` to the disavow file to disavow a whole domain, and all sub domains and pages of that domain from their backlinks.

In the case of the identified domain in the question disavowal of the entire domain is entirely appropriate as this is a known malicious site and to bypass detection and blocking uses a virtually unlimited number of sub domains and sub domains within sub domains up to 9 levels deep to create what effectively appears as a new fully qualified domain name.